# ItemUpdating Redirect Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, event-receiver, eventreceiver

I'm attempting to perform a redirect within an ItemUpdating event receiver but so far no luck.

I can't use SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl because my CSR Render Mode must be Standard and not a server render. I've tried other methods listed online, but they are all dated and provide me with the same error message "The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again."

Any suggestions?